# How to determine the binding context of a converter?

Tags: wpf, debugging, data-binding, converters

If I have an exception occurring in a converter, how can I work backwards from there to determine the binding that this converter is part of? Is there a way to determine the binding context that a converter is participating in?

I have Visual Studio breaking on this exception, so now I need to determine which UI element this converter is associated with, and consequently which property in which data object is being used for the source of the binding that is using the converter.

I'm well aware of all the other debugging methodologies when debugging a converter or binding from the other way, but in this case I don't know which binding is causing the issue, and it is not practical to search a very large solution to add information to each possible usage of this converter.

Comment: You are not getting binding error warnings?  I do.  Look at what your debugger reports.

Comment: @Paparazzi No, there is no binding information in the output because the binding isn't decorated with anything like a `PresentationTraceSources` setting, all I get is a stack trace.

Comment: OK, maybe a bulk update would work.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's not an option - the solution is around 150 projects, the particular screen this is happening on is a complicated one that relies on 20-30 of those projects. I'd rather use a surgical approach and  work backwards from the problem spot than a shotgun approach working forward. The usual debugging approaches are fine when you've already identified the problem binding, but when you have a commonly used converter and you don't know which binding it is happening on then those traditional methods get real expensive real fast.

Comment: OK, fine it will not work.  You may not have a surgical approach.